# How to change size of event element in FullCalendar DayGrid View?

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

In my FullCalendar rendering I use the dayGrid view to create a schedule. When populating this calendar view (schedule) with events, every event is the same height, regardless of the duration of the event. I would like to make the events bigger or smaller based on their duration, similar to what the FullCalendar demo shows for other calendar views. Is this possible to achieve using the dayGrid View?

My Calendar:
[image: MyCalendarImage]

FullCalendar Desired Styling:
[image: FullCalendarImage]

Comment: No you can't do that. The dayGrid has no concept of time, unlike the timeGrid, so there's no vertical axis by which it could stretch the events to the correct length. It's only intended as a high-level overview of the month. If you use MS Outlook's calendar or Google Calendar, you'll see they take a very similar approach in their month views too. It would quickly become very large, cluttered and unwieldy if events were stretched to their true length in those views, due to the number of days involved, and the grid system with rows. It would look horrendous and be unreadable.

Comment: If people want more detail, they can drill down to the week/day views - you can provide buttons in the fullCalendar header to allow this, and you can also make it so that if they click on a particular day it will switch to the detailed view for that day as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding a way to accomplish my goal. The CSS styling for the calendar rendering can be modified right in the html page using:

```
<style>
   .fc-day-grid-event > .fc-content {
       white-space: normal;
   }
</style>
```

This allows the text of the event title to wrap onto multiple lines. Without modifying this styling the event text (title) just cuts off anything longer than the width of the event box. 
Once this styling is in place, I can just insert newline characters ('\n') into my html in order to expand the size of the box. Because I am controlling my events from a database, it is easy to simply add newline characters into the title string corresponding to the desired size of the event.

Here is what my calendar looked like before:
[image: NoEventSizeControl]

And here are some sample events to recreate the image:

```
events: [
            {
            id: 'event1',
            title: 'Event 1- 5h',
            start: '2020-06-16',
            displayEventTime: false,
            editable: true,
            allDay: true
            },

            {
              id: 'event2',
              title: 'Event 2- 2h',
              start: '2020-06-16',
              displayEventTime: false,
              editable: true,
              allDay: true
            },

            {
                id: 'event3',
                title: 'Event 3- 1h',
                start: '2020-06-16',
                displayEventTime: false,
                editable: true,
                allDay: true
            }
]
```

Here is what the calendar looks like using my solution:
[image: EventSizingSolution]

And the simple modification to the events needed for this solution:

```
events: [
            {
            id: 'event1',
            title: 'Event 1- 5h' + '\n\n\n\n\n',
            start: '2020-06-16',
            displayEventTime: false,
            editable: true,
            allDay: true
            },

            {
              id: 'event2',
              title: 'Event 2- 2h' + '\n\n',
              start: '2020-06-16',
              displayEventTime: false,
              editable: true,
              allDay: true
            },

            {
                id: 'event3',
                title: 'Event 3- 1h',
                start: '2020-06-16',
                displayEventTime: false,
                editable: true,
                allDay: true
            }
]
```

Comment: Hey, this isnt working for me. I cant stretch the event. The text text still cuts off after changing the code according to your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

In v5 find in the CSS file .fc-h-event and add the height option. This is mine:

```
.fc-h-event { /* allowed to be top-level */
    display: block;
    height: 70px !important;
    border: 2px solid #3788d8;
    border: 2px solid var(--fc-event-border-color, #3788d8);
    background-color: #3788d8;
    background-color: var(--fc-event-bg-color, #3788d8)
}
```